# Image uploading function not working in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, image, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to build a Spring boot application that is able to take image  as input, save it then display that image as required.

Here is the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Team_Members")
public class TeamMembers {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="Member_Id")
    private int MemberId;
    
    @Column(name="Member_Name")
    private String MemberName;
    
    @Column(name="Position")
    private String Position;
    
    @Column(name="Picture")
    private String Picture;
    
    @Column(name="Password")
    private String Password;
    
    @Column(name="Bio", columnDefinition = "text")
    private String Bio;
```

Here is the controller:

```
@Controller
public class TeamMembersController {
    
    @Autowired
    TeamMembersRepository TeamRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    
    @RequestMapping("/teammembers")
    public String memberlist(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("Members",TeamRepo.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("command",new TeamMembers());
        return "teammembersback";
        
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value ="/savamember", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public String savemember(@RequestParam("MemberId") int Id, @RequestParam("MemberName") String Name, 
            @RequestParam("Position") String position, @RequestParam("password") String password, 
            @RequestParam("Bio") String bio, @RequestParam("Pic") MultipartFile pic) throws IllegalStateException, IOException, ParseException {
        TeamMembers member = new TeamMembers();
        member.setMemberId(Id);
        member.setMemberName(Name);
        member.setPosition(position);
        member.setPassword(password);
        member.setBio(bio);
        member.setPicture(pic.getOriginalFilename());
        TeamRepo.save(member);
        String filePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        pic.transferTo(new File(filePath+pic.getOriginalFilename()));
        return "forward:/teammembers";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/deletemember/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deletemember(@PathVariable int id){
        TeamRepo.deleteById(id);
        return "forward:/teammembers";
    }
```

Here is the jsp page:

```
<body>
<div class="starter-template">
   <h1>Team Members:</h1>
   <table
    class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tr>
     <th>Id</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Position</th>
     <th>Bio</th>
     <th>Password</th>
     <th>Photo</th>
     <th>Delete</th>
     
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="member" items="${Members}">
     <tr>
      <td>${member.memberId}</td>
      <td>${member.memberName}</td>
      <td>${member.position}</td>
      <td>${member.bio}</td>
      <td>${member.password}</td>
      <td><img width="100" src ="${member.picture}"></td>
      <td><a href="deletemember/${member.memberId}">Delete</a></td> 
     </tr>
    </c:forEach>
   </table>
  </div>

<h1>Add a new Member or Update an existing one</h1> 

<form method="post" action="savamember" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input name="MemberId" placeholder= "ID" type= "text" required>
       <input name="MemberName" placeholder= "Name" type= "text" required>
       <input name="Position" placeholder= "Position" type= "text" required>
       <lable for= "Pic">Pic:</lable>
       <input name="Pic" placeholder= "Pic" type= "file" required><br>
       <lable for= "Bio">Bio:</lable>
       <textarea type="text" id="Bio" name="Bio" rows="2" class="form-control md-textarea" required></textarea>
       <input name="password" placeholder= "Password" type= "text" required>
       <input type="submit" value="Add Staff" />
       </form> 

</body>
```

This code works perfectly when I run it in my local system but fails to function properly when I try the function in AWS EC2 instance. The program it self is running fine every thing is properly saved in the database including the image name, but the image itself is not being displayed in the table.  Do you guys any idea what could have went wrong?

Edit: Hey guys, I found the problem. you can't use `getRealPath()` nor you can upload any file directly into the app in war packaging. You have to save it in an external location, which I still haven't figured out how to do? I f you guys have any idea please, let me know.

Comment: DO you see an error message. App running on EC2 can handle file uploads.

Comment: @smac2020 the program is giving no error, I think the problem may be due file path on which the image is being save is different in cloud. I am  trying to look into it but for some reason the console is not working. I will share more detail as soon as I am able to verify that.

Comment: Is there an error message in your browser's developer console? Or in the network tab perhaps? There has to at least be an error in the browser that it can't download the image or something. Looking at the URL of the image that the browser is trying to display, and any error responses from the server, like a `404` would be extremely helpful in determining the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying a Spring Boot app that lets a user upload files is supported. There is an example that lets a user upload files into an Amazon S3 bucket - as shown in this illustration.

[image]

See this example:

[Detect objects in images with Amazon Rekognition using an AWS SDK](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app)

I suspect your issue is when manually confirging the EC2 instance, you are missing something. Instead of manully deploying a Spring Boot app, try using [Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html).

Benefits of using this is:

"With Elastic Beanstalk, you can quickly deploy and manage applications in the AWS Cloud without having to learn about the infrastructure that runs those applications. Elastic Beanstalk reduces management complexity without restricting choice or control. You simply upload your application, and Elastic Beanstalk automatically handles the details of capacity provisioning, load balancing, scaling, and application health monitoring."

I deployed the Spring Boot App using AWS Elatic Beanstalk instead of manually deploying to an EC2 instance with no issues. I recommend that you try deploying it using Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, I will immediately look into it. as I am still new to the AWS and hosting any and all pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: There is a link to how to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk at end of doc above. Its is much easier to deploy via Elastic Beanstlalk vs manually configuring  an EC2 instance yourself.  When deploying a Spring Boot app - make sure that you create a FAT JAR with all the required dependencies.